# Writing my own generic collection class

Tags: c#, list, generics, collections

I don't really know how to create my own collection class. I've searched around the net but I'm not sure what the declaration should look like.

Should I define the class like this? Advice and hints are appreciated!

```
namespace Myprog
{
    class mylist<t>
    {
     //Do something   

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  "Should I define the class like this" -- what is "this"?  Are you simply asking about how the generic type parameter should look?

Comment: I think thats what I'm asking. The generic class i want to make should work as a generic class, have the same properties like etc the list class. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: I've very rarely needed to write my own generic collection class, the existing ones are so versatile. So, unless you're doing this for fun, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: If your class should have the same properties as the list class, you should implement the IList<T> interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a collection like a List you should implement IEnumerable interface. Just a quick google search and a nice result: [Creating a Custom Generic Collection](http://en.csharp-online.net/Understanding_Generics%E2%80%94Creating_a_Custom_Generic_Collection)

If you just want some more knowledge about generics in .NET look at this MSDN [Generics (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) site and check links from there.

Comment: Dead link!... `Creating a Customer Generic Collection` is dead link. Please provide further details in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the following in Visual Studio:

```
public class MyImpl<T> : IList<T>
{
}
```

Now set the caret on `IList<T>` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and select *Implement interface IList*. You'll get the skeleton for all needed methods. Go on and implement then. ;)